# Incorrect signal predictions for Sequential Model

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, k-fold

I am running a signal processing experiment using python sci-kit learn. I have an elaborate question which spans across multiple steps during K-Fold validation and the consequent predictions. I am describing them below.

I have 8640 samples of signal data which I am splitting into Training (70%) and Validation (30%). This gives me 6048 samples of Training and 2592 samples of validation. I am dividing the validation samples further - into 2500 samples for K-Fold validation and 92 samples as unseen/live signal. My ultimate goal is to predict all 92 unseen/live samples correctly.

I am giving a code snippet below.

```
estimator = KerasClassifier(build_fn=lambda: model, epochs=350, batch_size=32, verbose=1)
estimator.fit(X_train, Y_train)  //These are 6048 samples

kfold = KFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True) 
results = cross_val_score(estimator, X_test[0:2500,:], Y_test[0:2500], cv=kfold)
print("Accuracy: %.2f%% (%.2f%%)" % (results.mean()*100, results.std()*100))

predictions = estimator.predict(X_test[2400:2492,:]) #These are the test samples already used for K-Fold
print(predictions)

predictions-2 = estimator.predict(X_test[2500:2592,:]) #These are totally unseen samples
print(predictions-2)
```

My results are:

1. Accuracy (K-fold validation) = 70%
2. Standard deviation in accuracy = 29%
3. All samples from 2400 to 2492 are predicted correctly
4. Only 12 samples from 2500 to 2592 are predicted correctly.

I would like to know, if I am going wrong in understanding somewhere. Why only so few unseen samples are predicted correctly, even though all the samples which are used for K-fold are predicted correctly?

I have further observed that whichever model I use (with different number of hidden nodes or different number of layers), the correctly predicted samples remain around 12 to 15.